# Lucene inverted index access count

Tags: lucene, inverted-index

In Lucene, I want to know about the number of accesses in inverted index.

Maybe, Lucene has the inverted index like this,

cat   dog
-----   -----
d01   d02
d02   d01
d03   d03
-----   -----

If I use query "cat dog", Lucene will access the inverted index consecutively.
I ask top-2 result then, with only 4 accesses Lucene will return d01, d02.
In that case, I want to know the access time (in this example "4").

Currently, I use Lucene like this.

```
Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_35, "title", analyzer).parse(querystr);
int hitsPerPage = 10;
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(index, true);
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage, true);
searcher.search(q, collector);
ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotically, if there are `p` matches and you're finding the top `k`, the time will be `p log k`. So in your case, `6 log 2 = 6`. (Of course with such small numbers, this formula gives ridiculous results).

See [this](http://philosophyforprogrammers.blogspot.com/2010/09/lucene-performance.html) for more info.

Note that "top two" doesn't mean "first two", but rather "two highest scoring". Depending on the weights in your example, it's possible that Lucene could ignore d03.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that Lucene will keep the inverted index sort by the term score. Therefore, in that example, "top two" was "two highest score". Do you mean that Lucene always access (p log k) time? I thought if Lucene has inverted index like that, Lucene will stop the access after 4th access. Am I wrong?

Comment: @prory: Documents are sorted by ID for each term, not by score. This is a faster way of doing it than sorting by score, but it's too long to explain here. All I can say is: read the linked blog post and attached paper. As one example, if the only words in d01 and d02 are "cat" and "dog", then Lucene will stop after the fourth access. But it's too complicated to say that it will always take only 4.